# Replace the word unchanged

Tags: nsis

How can the following command, the "$R0" to replace my constant, that is precisely the word "$R0" just be replaced.

```
FileWrite $R4 "IntCmp $R1 $R0 equel less more$\r$\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want the word "$R0" is precisely in these replaced. After compiling the output in this field:

IntCmp 11212 equel less more 11212 instead of the $R1 value is replaced, but instead of $R0 is empty, the variable is not read! But I'd just replaced its $R0

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
FileWrite $R4 "IntCmp $R1 $$R0 equel less more$\r$\n"
```

Comment: I want the word "$R0" is precisely in these replaced. After compiling the output in this field:

                  IntCmp 11212 equel less more 11212 instead of the $R1 value is replaced, but instead of $R0 is empty, the variable is not read! But I'd just replaced its $R0